# Can all typechecking occurrences of `coerce` safely be replaced with `unsafeCoerce`?

Tags: haskell, set, coerce

I believe the following is as safe as `Set.mapMonotonic coerce`. i.e. the worst that can happen is I will break the `Set` invariants if `a` or `b` have different `Ord` instances:

```
coerceSet :: Coercible a b=> Set.Set a -> Set.Set b
coerceSet = unsafeCoerce
```

Is that correct?

**EDIT**: relevant feature issue for `Set`: https://github.com/haskell/containers/issues/308

Comment: Fantastic question. I look forward to seeing a comprehensive answer; the GHC documentation itself is incredibly vague about what you're actually allowed to use `unsafeCoerce` for. It's got a couple rules of thumb, but isn't clear (to me at least) exactly whether those rules apply here or not! I hope we get a GHC internals expert to write in some real detail what is and isn't kosher.

Comment: @DanielWagner my experience with haskell libraries is the more unsafe something is the more cagey people get with their docs, unfortunately.

Comment: @jberryman, the more unsafe something is the less likely the people writing/documenting it understand just how unsafe it is, and the more likely it is to get more unsafe when something else in the compiler or a library changes. Safety rules for `unsafeDupablePerformIO` are pretty straightforward, but I doubt anyone could confidently give you reliable ones for almost any uses of `unsafeInlinePerformIO`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This *should* be safe.

A valid `coerce @a @b` can always be replaced with a valid `unsafeCoerce @a @b`. Why? Because, at the Core level, they are the same function, `coerce` (which just returns its input, like `id`). The thing is that `coerce` takes, as argument, a proof that the two things being coerced have the same representation. With normal `coerce`, this proof is an actual proof, but with `unsafeCoerce`, this proof is just a token that says "trust me". This proof is passed as a type argument, and so, by type erasure, has no effect on the behavior of the program. Thus `unsafeCoerce` and `coerce` are equivalent whenever both are possible.

Now, this isn't the end of the story for `Set`, because `coerce` doesn't work on `Set`. Why? Let's peek at its definition.

```
data Set a = Bin !Size !a !(Set a) !(Set a) | Tip
```

From this definition, we see that `a` does not appear inside any type equalities etc. This means that we have congruence of representational equality at `Set`: if `a ~#R b` (if `a` has the same representation as `b`—`~#R` is unboxed `Coercible`), then `Set a ~#R Set b`. So, from the definition of `Set` alone, `coerce` *should* work on `Set`, and thus your `unsafeCoerce` *should* be safe. The `containers` library has to use a specific

```
type role Set nominal
```

to hide this fact from the world, artificially disabling `coerce`. You can never disable `unsafeCoerce`, though, and, reiterating, `unsafeCoerce` (in this context) is safe.

(Do be careful that the `unsafeCoerce` and the `coerce` have the same type! See @dfeuer's answer for an example of a situation where "overzealous" type inference bends everything out of shape. )

Comment: Arguably, the library is a bit self-contradictory here, since it allows us to break the invariant using `mapMonotonic`, but disables `coerce` because it can break the invariant. This might be the pragmatic way to do it, though, since one can hardly miss the requirement of `mapMonotonic` and break it, while it would be easier to break it using `coerce` on a larger type which involves a set somewhere inside. Still, the library could  provide a way to enable safe coercions "on demand" on sets, e.g. using a `Dict`, letting the user guarantee that the types have the same ordering.

Comment: @chi I'm interested in your `Dict` idea but don't have much experience working with constraint kinds and so on. It would be neat if we could somehow get a `coerce` on sets that was _safer_ than `mapMonotonic`

Comment: @chi, `mapMonotonic` would be in a different, "unsafe", module if I'd been maintainer when it was added. But yes, being explicit is good. The only way to expose the optional coercion you want, with today's GHC, is to build it using `unsafeCoerce`. I'm thinking about a proposal to change that by removing the backwards reasoning from `Coercible` (it doesn't seem useful enough to justify these problems).

Comment: @chi, please see https://github.com/ghc-proposals/ghc-proposals/pull/276

Comment: Oh, the other option would of course be to make `Set` a newtype around an underlying internal `Set` type with a `representational` parameter role, but that would be a major implementation pain.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, this should be safe in typical realistic circumstances. However, it *is* possible to come up with contrived examples where it's not. Here's one that uses defaulting. I imagine it might be possible to use overlapping instances or other wacky features to do something similar, but I don't know.

```
{-# language GADTs, TypeOperators, ExistentialQuantification #-}

import Data.Coerce
import Unsafe.Coerce
import Data.Type.Equality

data Buh a = Buh (a :~: Rational) a

data Bah = forall a. Bah (a :~: Rational) a

instance Show Bah where
  show (Bah Refl x) = show x

goo :: Rational -> Bah
goo x = case coerce p of
          Buh pf m ->
            let _q = truncate m
            in Bah pf 12
  where
    p = Buh Refl x
```

If you call `goo`, everything will be fine. If you replace `coerce` with `unsafeCoerce`, calling `goo` will segfault or do something else bad.

Comment: I don't think this is particularly fair. You've turned `coerce @(Buh Rational) @(Buh Rational)` into `unsafeCoerce @(Buh Rational) @(Buh Double)`, by abusing the rules of type inference. This is not a problem with the `coerce`->`unsafeCoerce` substitution itself, since you haven't "really" substituted `unsafeCoerce` for `coerce` at all. I do agree this is rather alarming, though.

Comment: @HTNW, for sure. My point is that a blind syntactic substitution of one for the other may not be safe.